# Regular Expression to match first and last character of a word

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in which I want to make a regular expression in python to find three character repetend words who's first and last character should be same and middle one can any character

**Sample string**

s = 'timtimdsikmu`nmunju`ityakbonbonjdjjd`kitkat`ghdnj`samsun`ksuwjkhokhojeuhj`jimjam`jsju'

I want to extract all the highlighted words from above string...

My solution, but not matching with my requirement

```
import re

s='timtimdsikmunmunjuityakbonbonjdjjdkitkatghdnjsamsunksuwjkhokhojeuhjjimjamjsju'

re.findall(r'([a-z].[a-z])(\1)',s)
```

this is giving me this

```
[('tim', 'tim'), ('mun', 'mun'), ('bon', 'bon'), ('kho', 'kho')]
```

I want this

```
[('kit', 'kat'), ('sam', 'sun'), ('jim', 'jam'),('nmu', 'nju')]
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this can't be solved with a regex alone. The result of "findall" will then need some post-processing (removing some group matches from the tuples) to get the desired output.

Comment: Why is your output missing `'nmu', 'nju'` ?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for responding, Don't bother about the output form, I just want to extract those words it can be extracted in any format.

Comment: @anubhava oh sorry it's my mistake to add, let me update it

Comment: But why should `'nmu', 'nju'` not be in expected output when it meets your rule?

Comment: you can't catch samsun with a regex

Comment: @anubhava updated

Comment: Hard to get individual words since there could be many 3 letter words on each match. Using [(.)(.)(.)(?:\1(?!\2).\3)+](https://regex101.com/r/VNcxI8/1) gets the whole match, Group 1 and 3 contain the constant letters, then every 4th letter ( from 1 offset start ) is each individual  middle  letter which cannot be guaranteed to be unique in this context since there is not an infinite number of capture groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use capturing groups and references:

```py
s='timtimdsikmunmunjuityakbonbonjdjjdkitkatghdnjsamsunksuwjkhokhojeuhjjimjamjsju'

import re
out = re.findall(r'((.).(.)\2.\3)', s)
[e[0] for e in out]
```

output:

```
['timtim', 'munmun', 'bonbon', 'kitkat', 'khokho', 'jimjam']
```

##### ensuring the middle letter is different:

```py
[e[0] for e in re.findall(r'((.)(.)(.)\2(?!\3).\4)', s)]
```

output:

```
['nmunju', 'kitkat', 'jimjam']
```

###### edit: split output:

```
>>> [(e[0][:3], e[0][3:]) for e in re.findall(r'((.)(.)(.)\2(?!\3).\4)', s)]
[('nmu', 'nju'), ('kit', 'kat'), ('jim', 'jam')]
```

Comment: Much closer, But I just want to extract same repetend words of three character in which middle character must be different (Exact same repetend words are not allowed e.g. `timtim` `munmun` `bonbon` etc)

Comment: @Ali to my knowledge it is not feasible to use only `re.findall`, the list slicing is obligatory

Answer (score 3):

There is always the pure Python way:

```py
s = 'timtimdsikmunmunjuityakbonbonjdjjdkitkatghdnjsamsunksuwjkhokhojeuhjjimjamjsju'

result = []
for i in range(len(s) - 5):
    word = s[i:(i+6)]
    if (word[0] == word[3] and word[2] == word[5] and word[1] != word[4]):
        result.append(word)
    
print(result)
```

```
['nmunju', 'kitkat', 'jimjam']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex in python:

```
(?P<first>([a-z])(.)([a-z]))(?P<second>\2(?!\3).\4)
```

Group `first` is for first word and `second` is for the second word.

`(?!\3)` is negative lookahead to make sure second character is not same in 2nd word.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XY0KZ2/1)

```sh
import re

rx = re.compile(r"(?P<first>([a-z])(.)([a-z]))(?P<second>\2(?!\3).\4)")
s = 'timtimdsikmunmunjuityakbonbonjdjjdkitkatghdnjsamsunksuwjkhokhojeuhjjimjamjsju'
for m in rx.finditer(s): print(m.group('first'), m.group('second'))
```

**Output:**

```
nmu nju
kit kat
jim jam
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it faster with for loop:

```
result2 = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    try:
        if s[i] == s[i+3] and s[i+2] == s[i+5]:
            result2.append((s[i:i+3], s[i+3:i+6]))
    except IndexError:pass

print(result2)
```